# focus to field when bootstrap modal is opened

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Neither works this one:

```
    $formTemplateModal.modal('show');
    $('#form_template_name').focus();
```

nor a more complicated one:

```
    $formTemplateModal.modal('show').promise().done(function() {
        // @todo: does not work.
        $('#form_template_name').focus();
    });
```

field $('#form_template_name') is a input[type=text] and it surely exists and it belongs to $formTemplateModal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shown is changed in bootstrap 3 , 
Try this if it could help

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#textareaID').focus();
})
```

this is more easier try using the autofocus in your tag .

```
<textarea id="textareaID" autofocus="" ></textarea>
```

Comment: "Due to how HTML5 defines its semantics, the autofocus HTML attribute has no effect in Bootstrap modals." -- Bootstrap Modal docs

Comment: The `shown.bs.modal` approach is absolutely correct though.